# receive output from java DataOutputStream in a php page

Tags: java, php, applet, dataoutputstream

I have a java applet which I am using to send a file back to my server with - on the server end I want to receive this on a php page.

Below is the java code which is doing the sending, on the php side of things I have checked the global arrays and I have the data passed by the URL, but not the file data. I have really searched and scratched on this one so any help appreciated.

```
String strURL = sendToURL + "?ACTION=POST&LEN=" + imgBytes.length + "&Fname=picture.png";
    try{
        URL urlServlet = new URL(strURL);
        URLConnection sCon = urlServlet.openConnection();
        sCon.setDoInput(true);
        sCon.setDoOutput(true);
        if (sCon.getAllowUserInteraction()) {
            sCon.setAllowUserInteraction(true);
        }
        sCon.setUseCaches(false);
        sCon.setDefaultUseCaches(false);
        sCon.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/html");
        sCon.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        sCon.setConnectTimeout(transferTimeout);
        sCon.setReadTimeout(transferTimeout);
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(sCon.getOutputStream());

        int index = 0;
        size = 1024;
        do {
            if (index + size > imgBytes.length) {
                size = imgBytes.length - index;
            }
            out.write(imgBytes, index, size);
            index += size;
        } while (index < imgBytes.length);

        out.write(imgBytes);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
```

---

SOLVED - as so often happens one posts a question after days of battling and mere minutes later a solution presents.

I got thinking after the comment about using SOAP that I remembered using cURL for transferring XML data once before. a few searches later and I came across a much simpler and very elegant solution.

http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2008/Accessing-Incoming-PUT-Data-from-PHP

basically you can access the PUT data in php by using

```
file_get_contents("php://input")
```

so now it works awesomely

Comment: i don't think php is able to do what you want

Comment: That's what I was worried about - what I was considering is to somehow encode the file and then send it as part of the URL. Unfortunately I am very new to java so am not sure how to accomplish that either.

Answer (score 0):

i used a lot of times Soap Messages to get Data From PHP to Java that works fine

So Use PHP as Webservice and Communicate via SOAP

Setup a WSDL File

Generate Java Stubs and Skeletons
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/wsimport.html

Load WSDL into a php skript
http://www.php.net/manual/de/book.soap.php

```
   $soapClient = new SoapClient("blahblah.wsdl");
```

And do your logic in the php

Then use the Java Stubs to call the server and transmit your data