# PHP read input stream from Java DataOutputStream?

Tags: java, php, dataoutputstream

For a while, I've been working on a Java client that sends level information to save online. I have managed using printwriter, but it is really inefficient, and a simple 300KB level turns out to be 3MB after the transfer, and is rather slow.

I know people have used "file_get_contents("php://input")", such as in [receive output from java DataOutputStream in a php page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6767273/receive-output-from-java-dataoutputstream-in-a-php-page), but I am not sure how to receive specific data from:

```
//phpsend is the DataOutputStream using POST (java)
phpsend.writeUTF(username);
phpsend.writeUTF(verificationId);
phpsend.writeInt(levelsize);
phpsend.write(level); //level has been converted to a byte array
```

how would I read each separate write? I know Java had DataInputStream, which had all the corresponding read functions, but how would I do that in PHP? I've heard of "Sockets" and "SOAPClient", but I could not find any information that I could use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have found that

```
file_get_contents("php://input")
```

seems to do the what I want. Simply assign its result to a variable

```
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

and the `$data` get all Java sent.